# How to get Windows 10 Computer to see other computer's shared files& folders

Tags: windows, network-share

I have a small office network -- 2 Windows 7 Professional and 2 Windows 10 Home

Each of them machines has a certain folder and files within all shared for access on the LAN.

On each of the 2 Windows 7 Professional machines I can see and access everyone's shared folder and files. Perfect!

On each of the 2 Windows 10 Home machines I can only see and access the folders and files shared off the Windows 7 machines. I cannot see or access the shared folder and files on the other Windows 10 Home machine.

Is it possible to get shared access from one Windows 10 Home machine to another Windows 10 Home machine?

If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A recent update removed HomeGroup from Win10. This link might be helpful. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4092694/windows-10-changes-to-file-sharing-over-a-network

Comment: I tired that link and it does not solve the problem. File & Print sharing is turned on. Network Discovery is turned on. Yet when I type a user name that exists on the network I get a "Windows is unable to find user {username}"

Comment: You are typing .. usernames ... 'on the network'? What do you *exactly* do?